# Need guidance on saving an image to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, image, unity-game-engine

I've been piecing a few things together but I've hit a bit of a snag. This is my first attempt at saving an image to a server. I'm including the components I have worked up so far. cs script, php file and my table setup. Right now I'm saving to server but I'm getting empty entries. Can someone show me how to set things up properly in my code?

How do I transfer 'bytes' (byte array in C# file) to the server and save it in the 'image' blob? How do I pass the form.AddBinaryData paramaters and store them in the table that I've created?

---------- C# ----------

```
public string screenShotCGIURL= "https://locomoku.com/php/uploadSC.php";


public void TakeScreenshot() 
{ 
    StartCoroutine("UploadPNG"); 
}

IEnumerator UploadPNG()
{
    // We should only read the screen buffer after rendering is complete
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    // Create a texture the size of the screen, RGB24 format
    int width = Screen.width;
    int height = Screen.height;
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

    // Read screen contents into the texture
    tex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, width, height/2), 0, 0);
    tex.Apply();

    // Encode texture into PNG
    byte[] bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();
    Object.Destroy(tex);

    // Create a Web Form
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    string file_name = "animalmatch_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-mm-ss");
    file_name = file_name+".png";
    // ref_link_screenshot = s_name;

    Debug.Log(file_name);

    // Upload to a cgi script
    WWW upload = new WWW(screenShotCGIURL, form);

    form.AddField("image_id", "");
    form.AddField("image_type", "image/png");
    form.AddBinaryData("image", bytes, file_name, "image/png");
    form.AddField("image_size", bytes.Length);
    form.AddField("image_name", file_name);


    yield return upload;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(upload.error)) {
        print(upload.error);
    }
    else {
        print("Finished Uploading Screenshot");
    }
```

---------- PHP ----------

```
$db_host        =   "localhost";    // MySQL Host Name.

$db_user        =   "********";     // MySQL User Name.

$db_password    =   "********";     // MySQL Password.

$db_name        =   "********";     // MySQL Database Name.


$imgData = file_get_contents($filename);
$size = getimagesize($filename);

mysql_connect("$db_host", "$db_user", "$db_password");
mysql_select_db ("$db_name");

$sql = "INSERT INTO screenshot
    (image_id ,image_type ,image, image_size, image_name)
    VALUES
    ('', '{$size['mime']}', '{$imgData}', '{$size[3]}', 
     '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}')";

mysql_query($sql);
```

----------mySQL ----------

```
image_id        tinyint(6)  not null default '0',

image_type      varchar(25) not null default '',

image           largeblob   not null,

image_size      varchar(25) not null default '',

image_name      varchar(50) not null default ''
```

Comment: php runs on the server, and your c# runs wherever it runs. the two system are NOT inter-compatible and variables used on one are utterly unknown/useless to the other.  your php has `$filename` defined, you're simply assuming the file upload succeeded, and you are also vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: depending on the size of the file, blob may not be sufficient enough, should that be the case. Try  MEDIUMBLOB or LONGBLOB  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html - check for errors everywhere.

Comment: Thanks makes sense Marc. So how do I transfer 'bytes' (in C#) to the server and save it in the 'image' blob? How do I pass the  form.AddBinaryData paramaters and store them on my server?

Comment: You will need to pass the array from C# to PHP when you perform the upload. You can store in the MySQL DB or you can post it via HTTP to a PHP Handler. Last ditch would be to drop the data into a browser cookie via C# and then read from that cookie with PHP. Basically you need to pass the data via something both can use.

Comment: One other, you could write the data into a flat file with C#, much like you do with the image itself, and then open and read it into PHP. Could use JSON, XML, etc format since both can use that.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to store it in the MySQL DB. What do I need to edit in my code to make that work? I don't know how to make the remaining connections to pass things to the server.

Comment: Based on the code I have written above, can someone tell me why this isn't writing the screenshot to the MySQL DB? Could someone point out my errors?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact same problem when trying to upload .png from Unity to my database, but I found a way to solve it.
Bear with me that I am new to this stuff so I am not sure if this is the perfect solution but it works:

Your C# script looks fine. Uploading the -png with the AddBinaryData looks similar to what I did. However, the entries never listed properly in the db.
This is because what we get from the PHP-script's $_FILES['image'] is an *array* with the following attributes:

```
$_FILES['userfile']['name']
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
$_FILES['userfile']['size']
$_FILES['userfile']['type']
```

None of these attributes contain the content as we are looking for, right, only string of names and types and the like. So we have to open a file stream to extract our actual content, our png image.

Add the following to your PHP code:

```
$tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

Then add the $content variable in your SQL query as shown below:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO screenshot (Image) VALUES ('$content')";
mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('Error, sql query failed');
```

[This](http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx) page and some whisky helped me solve it. Hope it can help you too if my solution is not an exact match to what you were looking for.

Good luck!

PS:
I see you use your database connection settings in your php file. Many sites like W3schools and such still keep this up but if you are unlucky the information may leak.

You could replace that code with this:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('../config/config.ini');
```

Then keep a **config.ini** in another inaccessible directory looking like this:

```
[database]
servername = ***
username = ***
password = ***
dbname = ***
```

PHP have good support for ini-files. To make the directory inaccessible in an Apache environment you cold add a .htaccess script saying simply:

```
Deny from all
```

DS